# For loop to fill NA with dates

Tags: date, for-loop

I have a DF with consecutive dates with some NA's following, also worth mentioning is [1] will always have a Date.

I wish to fill the proceeding NA's with consecutive dates.

I have : "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", NA, NA

Expected outcome within the DF will be: 
"2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05"

I attempted to use a for loop but I am fairly amateur at this:

```
Date <-as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", NA, NA))

DF <- as.data.frame(Date)

i <- which.max(is.na(DF$Date))
for (i in which.max(is.na(DF$Date)):max(length(DF$Date))){
  if(is.na(DF$Date)){
    DF$Date[i]= as.Date(max(DF$Date, na.rm=TRUE) + 1)
  }
}
```

It returns this:

Warning messages:

```
1: In if (is.na(DF$Date)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(DF$Date)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself, the if statement wasn't a single value it was listing the whole DF if true or false NA.

```
Date <-as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", NA, NA))

DF <- as.data.frame(Date)

i <- which.max(is.na(DF$Date))
for (i in which.max(is.na(DF$Date)):max(length(DF$Date))){
  if(which.max(is.na(DF$Date))){
    DF$Date[i]= as.Date(max(DF$Date, na.rm=TRUE) + 1)
  }
}
```